# How to keep main menu collapsed when accessing subpages on small devices in Django?

Tags: html, css, django

I have a website that I built in Django. I have a problem when the website is opened in a small device (smartphone). If I open the website in a small device the main menu on the main webpage collapses into a hamburger (this is desidered), but once I go to a subpage, the main menu expands completely looking awful. The main webpage and subpages have a base that is used in both.

[image: Collapsed main menu on the main webpage]

[image: Expanded main menu on a subpage]

Below are the packages and versions I am currently using:

```
Django==3.2.5
django-mathfilters==1.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
httplib2==0.14.0
numpy==1.21.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
Pillow==7.0.0
pipreqs==0.4.10
requests==2.22.0
simplejson==3.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
urllib3==1.25.8
whitenoise==5.3.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
boto3==1.18.42
django-storages==1.11.1
psycopg2
django_heroku
```

I expect the main menu on both types of pages: home or subpages, to be shown as a hamburger/collapsed option.